# How to get the flavor of the root project in a child project's build.gradle in case of Multi project setup in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

We are having multi project setup of our android app with more than one flavor is present in the root project.

Our requirement is to get the root project's flavor for which this apk is being constructed in child library project's build gradle.

In android, we can run task to build all flavor in one go only. Is it possible that we can detect parent root project's current flavor for which this library is going to be packaged in build process only.

Please help.

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, but it seems like a bad design to have the child library project dependent on state in the parent project's build. In theory a library project ought to be able to stand on its own.

Comment: @ScottBarta Actually, library projects in android are always built with **release** version.  This is a problem if one needs to debug code from the library project.  Therefore, flags like `defaultPublishConfig "debug"` must be set in the library project to circumvent this issue.